# CPU overheating. What can I do?

Tags: cpu

I've experienced a few emergency shutdowns due to overheating. (Always while playing Minecraft) I checked what `sensors` would say me and I got this reply:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +52.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 0:         +52.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 1:         +48.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
```

This means I have to keep my CPU temp below 85°C. How can I achieve this? I've tried to use LXDE for gaming, which reduced the nuber of overheatings, but they still are there.

I've read through the `/var/log/kern.log.1` and found these lines at the crash time:

```
Nov  3 12:12:27 dracarys kernel: [ 1466.805429] CPU1: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Nov  3 12:12:27 dracarys kernel: [ 1466.805432] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Nov  3 12:12:27 dracarys kernel: [ 1466.805438] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Nov  3 12:12:27 dracarys kernel: [ 1466.806434] CPU1: Core temperature/speed normal
Nov  3 12:12:27 dracarys kernel: [ 1466.806436] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
Nov  3 12:12:27 dracarys kernel: [ 1466.806440] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
Nov  3 12:13:00 dracarys kernel: [ 1499.816082] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
Nov  3 12:13:44 dracarys kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Nov  3 12:13:44 dracarys kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Nov  3 12:13:44 dracarys kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Nov  3 12:13:44 dracarys kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 3.8.0-32-generic (buildd@lamiak) (gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) ) #47-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 22:35:23 UTC 2013 (Ubuntu 3.8.0-32.47-generic 3.8.13.10)
Nov  3 12:13:44 dracarys kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-32-generic root=UUID=217614be-d869-4303-8ca9-92fb8680dde6 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

it says the temperature could be brought down again, but the computer yet switched off.

Comment: The output here is not of an overheating CPU, rather it's from one that's been under moderate load but it's well within the limits. Can you check to see what temperature your CPU is actually getting to when it crashes?

Comment: If your machine is a Macbook Pro or other Apple hardware, checkout https://github.com/dgraziotin/Fan-Control-Daemon for proper fan control.

Comment: @AidenBell won't be of use for me... btw. I haven't been using this computer for over two months now... got a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a program just for this problem. Limit your CPU based on a desired temperature. It runs like this:

```
sudo ./temp_throttle.sh 80
```

That command will make your CPU cores slow down when they reach 80 degrees Celsius. You can find [temp_throttle here](http://seperohacker.blogspot.com/2012/10/linux-keep-your-cpu-cool-with-frequency.html).

Comment: Shouldn't the cores already be slowing down, since the logs say they are being throttled? Doesn't your script do the same thing system should already be doing?

Answer (score 5):

Each core has their own values, for some ~90°C is normal operating temperature. There are several reasons why your CPU could overheat. Kernel issues, stopped fans, bad fan/temperature management, dusty airflows, etc, etc.

You literally have to tackle every reason (some of them cannot) and see what works.

Comment: 90°C is way too hot for a CPU in my experience. For example, even [the big desktop CPUs](http://ark.intel.com/products/75123/Intel-Core-i7-4770K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) specify a maxiumum external temp (TCASE) of 72°C

Comment: @Oli I'm thinking on load, and P4 were/are like that.

Comment: The mobile Core i7 is allowed for even 105°C: http://ark.intel.com/products/85215/Intel-Core-i7-5600U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz