# Is 55°C a Safe Temperature for a Acer Aspire One D255?

Tags: acer, ubuntu-netbook, temperature

I am new to using Ubuntu on Laptops and Netbooks.

I was wondering if this is a safe/good temperature.

> Adapter: Virtual device
>
> temp1: +55.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

If not how can I fix this, I don't want to run the Windows 7 Starer Again also the side of the laptop feels a bit warm and I am not sure about that cues there is only one vent and I assume that is just the hot air being pushed out.

Answer (score 2):

No, 55°C is not dangerous. While the specific limit temperatures will depend on your hardware, the output you show states that the critical temperature is 100°C. Since you are at approximately half that, I wouldn't worry about it.

Note that this does not apply across the board. Just in this particular case where you know the critical temperature. Anyway, 55 is low for just about anything, I don't think there is any component that will have issues with such a low temperature.

Comment: "half way" speaking of temperatures is ...dangerous. He is at 328 Kelvin, and the critical temperature is 373 K... :-))) (to the OP --- don't worry, terdon is right. My asus is normally around 65 °C).(Sorry, couldn't resist. In °F is even safer!).

Comment: @Rmano lol, I'd love to see the performance of hardware running at 55°K!

Comment: I *did* measure MOSFET at 10 °K back in time. They're good and fast. Pity the weld joints broke just looking bad at them...

Comment: @Rmano 10 _K_ seriously? Wow, of course they broke!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link for temp_throttle script [CPU overheating. What can I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370415/cpu-overheating-what-can-i-do/395659#395659)
I added it to startup applications list. It lowers speed of CPU when it reaches to critical level defined by you, like:

```
sudo '/home/$USER/helper/temp_throttle.sh'  55
```